создание виртуального сетевого интерфейса (с помощью python)
Насколько я понимаю, при использовании VPN создаётся виртуальный сетевой интерфейс (wintun), так как у меня Windows 11.
Можно ли мне создать такой интерфейс самостоятельно? И если да, то можно ли сделать это автоматически с помощью Python?
Также интересно, возможно ли настроить все остальные приложения на использование этого интерфейса?

Необходимо уточнить вопрос: можно ли создать сетевой интерфейс, при наличии уже установленного драйвера wintune или можно ли создать сетевой интерфейс, автоматизировав процесс установки нужного дистрибутива (через Интернет). Или Вам нужно вообще, что-то другое?

@Daemon-5 мне как раз нужно узнать если такой модуль для python под виндовс 11 чтобы он сделал tun интрефейс проблема в том что под мою винду я не нашел ничего подобного только под линукс

ну вроде бы легко гуглится похожий модуль python-pytuntap
